# Why is the following file extension regex not matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code:

```
isValid = field.uploads.forEach(upload => {
  console.log(upload.file)
  console.log('ext:', _.getFileExt(upload.file.name))
  console.log('reg:', regex)
  console.log('res:', regex.test(_.getFileExt(upload.file.name)))
})
```

These are the logs:

```
ext: jpg
reg: /^.*\.(.jpg)$/i
res: false
```

As you can see, even if the file is jpg the regex returns false. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

Here are the utility functions:

```
_.listToRegex = (array) => {
  return new RegExp('^.*\\.(' + array.join('|') + ')$', 'i')
}

_.getFileExt = (string) => {
  return string.split('.').pop()
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `.` in the pattern next to `jpg`. Remove it. However, the `_.listToRegex` does not actually add the dot to the pattern. There is something else in the code that might be adding it. Also, with `regex.test(_.getFileExt(upload.file.name))` you test `jpg` with a full string regex, it will be false as there is no `.` in the `_.getFileExt(upload.file.name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems as far as I can tell. First, your regular expression has an error. Second, you have to decide whether the regular expression that you are creating is intended to match against **file names** or **file extensions**.

**1.** The regex that was logged to the console contains an extra period, as pointed out in the comments above. `/^.*\.(.jpg)$/i` could be condensed to `/\.(jpg)$/i` if you only intend to use the expression to test for validity. You did not seem to show the assignment of your regex variable, so it is difficult to gauge how exactly the error arose, but my best guess is that you called your `listToRegex` utility like:

```
var regex = _.listToRegex(['.jpg'])
```

The `.` in the string `'.jpg'` would cause the introduction of the extra period. You could replace that code with:

```
var regex = _.listToRegex(['jpg'])
```

**2.** Secondly, you seem to be testing your regular expression against the file extension, when I think you want to test it against a file name.

```
regex.test(upload.file.name) //=> true
```